# How to return a xml document using React

Tags: html, reactjs, xml, amazon-s3, frontend

I need to return the sitemap dynamically for our sites, so when you type [www.oursite1.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.oursite1.com/sitemap.xml), should appear our sitemap.

To do this, I have a function in backend that return our XML from S3 to React, and React should show it on screen, but I am struggling with it. Here is how I am doing it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { create } from 'apisauce'
import ReactXmlParser from 'react-xml-parser';


function Sitemap():any {
    const [xml, setXML] = useState<any>('')

    useEffect(() => {
        if(xml === ''){
            const api = create({
                baseURL: "http://localhost:8085",
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"}
            })
         
            console.log("Fetching SITEMAP!")
            api.get('/sitemap').then(response => {
                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const xml = parser.parseFromString(String(response.data), 'text/xml');
                setXML(xml)
                console.log(xml)
            })
        }
    })

    return <>{xml}</>
}

export default Sitemap
```

And I receive it: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FM0r.png)
I don't know if Google Search Console accepts a XML as string, but if it doesn't, I need to do this conversion.

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find a solution? @Felipalds

Comment: @nerdess no, I changed the form that I uploaded to Google Ads. I am putting the S3 url instead